# PHP: how to use assert

Tags: php

In PHP, what are the best practices you following when using asserts? I'm curious about general use of asserts and PHP specific practices.

Comment: This would probably go better in http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Design By Contract

I believe assert is not used much in PHP. You could use it if you [Design By Contract](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract).

> Design by Contract (DbC) or
>   Programming by Contract is an approach
>   to designing computer software. It
>   prescribes that software designers
>   should define formal, precise and
>   verifiable interface specifications
>   for software components, which extend
>   the ordinary definition of abstract
>   data types with preconditions,
>   postconditions and invariants. These
>   specifications are referred to as
>   "contracts", in accordance with a
>   conceptual metaphor with the
>   conditions and obligations of business
>   contracts.

This [tutorial](http://www.terminally-incoherent.com/blog/2008/06/05/design-by-contract-in-php-with-assertions/) explains it a little bit.

### TDD / Unit Test

I would instead advise you to unit test your code(TDD) following these [3 simple rules](http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.TheThreeRulesOfTdd)(must read article).

> 1. You are not allowed to write any production code unless it is to make a
>      failing unit test pass.
> 2. You are not allowed to write any more of a unit test than is sufficient
>      to fail; and compilation failures are
>      failures.
> 3. You are not allowed to write any more production code than is
>      sufficient to pass the one failing
>      unit test.
>
> You must begin by writing a unit test
>   for the functionality that you intend
>   to write. But by rule 2, you can't
>   write very much of that unit test. As
>   soon as the unit test code fails to
>   compile, or fails an assertion, you
>   must stop and write production code.
>   But by rule 3 you can only write the
>   production code that makes the test
>   compile or pass, and no more.
>
> If you think about this you will
>   realize that you simply cannot write
>   very much code at all without
>   compiling and executing something.
>   Indeed, this is really the point.

To practice(discipline) this you should use the excellent [PHPUnit](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/index.html) framework. You should read this [Writing Tests for PHPUnit](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html) to get a feeling for this discipline.